# android google maps not loading the map when using GoogleMap.AnimateCamera()

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

**Google Maps document**

According to [Google maps document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views#updating_the_camera_view), in order to apply a CameraUpdate to the map, we can either move the camera instantly(by using GoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdate))
 or animate the camera smoothly(by using GoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdate)).

**What I did**

So I started by using GoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdate). The map can be loaded just fine. However, when I used GoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdate), the map can't be loaded. What I saw was just a gray screen or a blur map. The map would be fully loaded or became clear again unless I moved it manually.

Could anyone please tell me what is the problem? Does it require somethings else when working with GoogleMap.animateCamera()?

**Updated**: 
I just found a big mistake in my code and really sorry that I had not described it clear enough.
I used GMap.animateCamera() to update the camera whenever the heading of the device changed(used rotation sensor...). This happens too fast so cameraAnimation() can never finish its work. that's why the map can't be fully loaded either.

```
onDeviceHeadingChange(){
   val cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder(mMap.cameraPosition)
                                    .target(myLatLng)
                                    .bearing(myBearing)
                                    .tilt(50f)
                                    .build()
    val cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition)
    // the map will be loaded just fine with this method
    // mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate)

    // the problem appeared when I update camera with aniteCamera()
    mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate, 500, null)
}
```

**Map when use animateCamera**: [image]

**Map when use moveCamera**:[image]

**Solved**

```
onDeviceHeadingChange(){
   if(!cameraIsMoving){
      cameraIsMoving = true
      val cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder(mMap.cameraPosition)
                                    .target(myLatLng)
                                    .bearing(myBearing)
                                    .tilt(50f)
                                    .build()
       val cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition)
       mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate, 500, object: GoogleMap.CancelableCallback{
                                    override fun onFinish() {
                                        cameraIsMoving = false
                                    }

                                    override fun onCancel() {
                                        cameraIsMoving = false
                                    }
                                })
    }
}
```

This take me to a new question
**Why GoogleMap.moveCamera() can handle those call? but GoogleMap.animateCamera() can't?**

Comment: Did you add your gMaps API key in manifest it looks something like this
 ` <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />`

Comment: post your manifest.xml file

Comment: @trinadhthatakula yes, I did. that's why GoogleMap.moveCamera() can load the map just fine

Comment: @amin there're a lot of stuffs in manifest. but what related to google maps is only


<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />


<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, I had been looking for a long time for anyone with a similar issue. Great work at finding the issue yourself! Link to my SO question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71851064/google-maps-android-api-very-slow-to-download-and-display-map-image

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
LatLng initialLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(initialLocation, 18.0f));
```

I use it to animate map to a particular location with LatLng, I have never tried tilt though

Comment: Thank brother but didn't work. I cleared application catch and restart the app. I saw only a gray screen. The map didn't load unless I start moving the map manually.

Answer (score -1):

1. Try to change `.builder(mMap.cameraPosition)...` to `.builder()...`
2. Make sure you are calling this method after `onMapReady` callback

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried but didn't work. 
yes, for sure this method can only be called after onMapReady() callback