# Google Maps Android API very slow to download and display map image

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am using the default Google Maps example out of android studio, slightly modified to fit my project and when moving down the road the map tiles are very slow to load, sometimes don't populate the map until the marker is almost up against the blank aria then it loads all the streets up ahead and your good to drive another few blocks.
I have a GPS service running in the background which sends a location data broadcast to my receiver to update the marker and pan the map to the new location. It is when the map pans to this location that it is not updating the image properly.

```
marker.setRotation(bearing);
speed.setText(Speed);
CameraPosition newCamPos = new CameraPosition(location,
       zoom,
       55,
       bearing);
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(newCamPos), 1000, null);
```

First picture is when it is auto updating the map, second is when I touched it and moved the map a bit then it fills in properly.
[image: First Picture]

[image: Second Picture]